# Can I do arithmetic with complex numbers in awk, and if so how?

Tags: awk

Does the AWK language support arithmetic for complex numbers? If yes, how do I define an imaginary unit?

Comment: I do not believe that awk natively supports complex numbers.

Comment: I edited the title of your question to be more specific, as "complex arithmetics" can easily be read as "evaluate complicated equations" which is not the same as "doing arithmetic involving complex numbers".

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? For arbitrary precision operations with complex numbers (and much more) you can use [calc](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/).

Comment: Use `guile` instead, :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always define complex numbers as an array of two numbers (the real and imaginary part). You'd need to define all the arithmetic operators by hand:

```
function cset(x, real, imaginary) {
  x["real"] = real
  x["imaginary"] = imaginary
}

function cadd(n1, n2, result) {
  result["real"] = n1["real"] + n2["real"]
  result["imaginary"] = n1["imaginary"] + n2["imaginary"]
}
function cmult(n1, n2, result) {
  result["real"] = n1["real"] * n2["real"] - n1["imaginary"] * n2["imaginary"]
  result["imaginary"] = n1["real"] * n2["imaginary"] + n2["real"] * n1["imaginary"]
}
function c2a(x, tmp) {
  if (x["real"]) {
    tmp = x["real"]
    if (x["imaginary"] > 0) tmp = tmp "+"
  }
  if (x["imaginary"]) {
    if (x["imaginary"] == -1) tmp = tmp "-i"
    else if (x["imaginary"] == 1) tmp = tmp "i"
    else tmp = tmp x["imaginary"] "i"
  }
  if (tmp == "") tmp = "0"
  return "(" tmp ")"
}

BEGIN {
  cset(i, 0, 1)
  cmult(i, i, i2)
  printf "%s * %s = %s\n", c2a(i), c2a(i), c2a(i2)
  cset(x, 1, 2)
  cset(y, 0, 4)
  cadd(x, y, xy)
  printf "%s + %s = %s\n", c2a(x), c2a(y), c2a(xy)
}
```

Which would output:

```
(i) * (i) = (-1)
(1+2i) + (4i) = (1+6i)
```

For languages with native support for complex numbers, see:

- `python`:

  ```
  $ python -c 'print(1j*1j)'
  (-1+0j)
  ```
- `octave`:

  ```
  $ octave --eval 'i*i'
  ans = -1
  ```
- [`calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/) (`apcalc` package on Debian):

  ```
  $ calc '1i * 1i'
          -1
  ```
- `R`:

  ```
  $ $ Rscript -e '1i*1i'
  [1] -1+0i
  ```

Comment: Just to add to this... C++ reads/writes complex using the format `(real,imag)`.  You can read the individual real and imaginary components into AWK by adding parentheses and commas to the field separator.

`BEGIN {FS="[(, )]"}`

Answer (score 4):

No, awk does not currently support complex numbers natively.

I'll point to the [POSIX specification for awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) where it says:

> Each expression shall have either a string value, a numeric value, or both. Except as stated for specific contexts, the value of an expression shall be implicitly converted to the type needed for the context in which it is used. A string value shall be converted to a numeric value either by the equivalent of the following calls to functions defined by the ISO C standard:
>
> setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
>
> numeric_value = atof(string_value);
>
> or by converting the initial portion of the string to type double representation ...

and

> In case (a) the numeric value of the numeric string shall be the value that would be returned by the strtod() call ...

... and pointing out that [`atof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atof.html) and [`strtod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) both return a type of `double`.